# Different encryption is created for the same value

Tags: c#, encryption

I have used below code to encrypt my value. However, I noticed that for the same value new encryption format is generated instead of same encryption value. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Example:
Value is HelloWorld123$
When I executed for the first time, I am getting this encryption - EAAAAE+WzLTCsNOJSQBuTwnRsfrRxqLa6WLVr0zWQ8eozkr1

When I executed for the second time, I am getting this encryption - EAAAAEJuBne0limVQ4aQij89v2SjU8eHasyDlnsGGQ1MD43V

**Question: How can I solve to get same encryption all time for same value?**

```
  private static byte[] _salt = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }; // Array of numbers
    internal static byte[] key = { 0x0A, 01, 02, 0x48 };


    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypt the given string using AES.  The string can be decrypted using 
    /// DecryptStringAES().  The sharedSecret parameters must match.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="plainText">The text to encrypt.</param>
    /// <param name="sharedSecret">A password used to generate a key for encryption.</param>
    private static string EncryptStringAES(string plainText, string sharedSecret)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
        //    throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        string outStr = null;          // Encrypted string to return
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null; // RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.

        try
        {
            // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

            // Create a RijndaelManaged object
            aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
            aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // prepend the IV
                msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
                msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                }
                outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
            if (aesAlg != null)
                aesAlg.Clear();
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return outStr;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypt the given string.  Assumes the string was encrypted using 
    /// EncryptStringAES(), using an identical sharedSecret.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText">The text to decrypt.</param>
    /// <param name="sharedSecret">A password used to generate a key for decryption.</param>
    private static string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText, string sharedSecret)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
        //    throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
        // used to decrypt the data.
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        try
        {
            // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.                
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                // with the specified key and IV.
                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
                // Get the initialization vector from the encrypted stream
                aesAlg.IV = ReadByteArray(msDecrypt);
                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
            if (aesAlg != null)
                aesAlg.Clear();
        }

        return plaintext;
    }

    private static byte[] ReadByteArray(Stream s)
    {
        byte[] rawLength = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        if (s.Read(rawLength, 0, rawLength.Length) != rawLength.Length)
        {
            throw new SystemException("Stream did not contain properly formatted byte array");
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(rawLength, 0)];
        if (s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != buffer.Length)
        {
            throw new SystemException("Did not read byte array properly");
        }

        return buffer;
    }
```

User Case:

I have a form which insert form value into database. Including some valuable items which are encrypted.
I have another form which checks whether value exist in database, When I using some method for some lookup functions I need to compare many condition for the same value. So I am directly coparing encrypted values. But as new value is created. I am unable to compare those value

Hope I am able to explain mu Use Case

Comment: Do they both still decrypt to Hello World? If so, why do you want them to be the same output? (If you're storing a password you should be hashing, not encrypting)

Comment: Decrypt works fine but not Encrypt. Both Decrypt same value.

Comment: What does that mean? Do both encrypted strings decrypt to "Hello workd"?

Comment: Yes both Encrypted String return same Value as HelloWorld123$

Comment: Why do you want it to encrypt to the same value every time? Are you going to do a lookup on it?

Comment: Yes I am going to lookup on it. for some stored procedure

Comment: Please describe more fully what your use case is for this. "for stored procedure" is not a use case. For example: Are you encrypting a password one time and then expecting to take the user input, encrypt it and compare the encrypted strings and if same, decide that the password is correct?

Comment: Yes something like this I am doing it.

Comment: Deterministic encryption, like AES-SIV, might be appropriate. I don’t have any .NET packages implementing it to recommend, though.

Comment: Can you more clearly describe this use case? Why do you want to encrypt data then look up by the encrypted data? Do you ever want to decrypt the data?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netcore-3.1

This class uses a pseudorandom number generator in its work, which means that it is *supposed* to generate different data over time which means that your encrypted data is *supposed* to change. It always decrypts the same, but it isn't intended to be deterministic (producing same output for same inputs)

If you're doing something like storing a password you should use a hashing function (eg SHA256) rather than an encrypting function; they produce the same output for given inputs so you can compare the output today to the output yesterday and if they're the same you can decide that the user typed the same password today as he did yesterday

Ultimately you are probably in (or should want to be in) one of two places:

- you need to store some data securely and be able to retrieve it and turn it back into the data it was, maybe because you're the only person who knows it but it needs to be used or known elsewhere. You need to **encrypt** the data for storage, decrypt it, use it, if you update it you need to re-encrypt and store it again
- you need to be able to confirm some data that someone else knows; they will give you the data and you will check your record and decide whether they got it right or not. You need to **hash** the data then forget the original, the next time the person appears claiming they know the original data you hash what they claim it is and compare the hashes. If it's the same then their claim they know the data is correct

You might be wanting to have an encryption that is deterministic, but it's quite a rare thing to want and it feels more like you're misunderstanding some aspect of your use case. Go into more detail so we can better advise

Comment: Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

If you encrypt the same value it will give you different result, it’s basically security and most of the encryptions work in this manner.

If it gives you same results on each encryption then it will be deterministic and should be avoided.

Comment: Then what should be the work around? Can you suggest something?

Comment: You should always look for the decrypted value

Comment: I have multiple values stored in the database. I would take a lot of time to go back and forth to decrypt value then compare if not matched decrypt another value. This would take a lot of time

Comment: As caius described above you can use hashing function

Comment: Can Hashing can be decrypted when it is needed?

Comment: No, it cannot. that's why it is secure. Hashing is not encrypting, and you don't "dehash"

Comment: It feels like there something you're misunderstanding about the whole thing; can you talk us through more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: No I get the point. I am using Hashing to encrypt the data and I was able to accomplish with what I wanted to

Comment: @user1413 you could add an extra field that holds a hash fingerprint. You can use that one to check if something might be the same value and only decrypt those entries to check for equality while maintaining the ability to decrypt the values

Comment: @user1413 when you say "using hashing to encrypt" you show that you actually don't get the point. Hashing is not encrypting, hashing is one way and multiple different values can have the same hash value.